# layout problem and help me a solution to scale in all device

Tags: android

My image in some device is just fine , but in some small display phone ,the position of the image is out of range

Help me out PLS

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="198dp"
            android:layout_height="182dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="107dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="77dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="107dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="472dp"
            android:src="@drawable/hi"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: `android:layout_width="198dp"
            android:layout_height="182dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="107dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="77dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="107dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="472dp"` why you set hardcoded values? this is the main reason.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your xml by this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/Hi"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.06"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This is not so good answer - you are using fixed size everywhere and his screen will not look the same for all devices, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using fixed size on view your screen will not be responsive because different devices got different screen size and what may look good on some screens won't necessarily look good and another screen with different screen size.

To fix this - Don't use fixed size on your view - it will mnae you screen not responsive, use [constrainLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) with some [guidlines](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Guideline) 
 instead:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">




<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="todo"
    android:src="@drawable/common_full_open_on_phone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2"  />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this library https://github.com/intuit/sdp . It presents a new scale unit called `sdp` (scalable dp) that will auto scale your views depending on your device.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all the margins and paddings (They are prefer to be used for a smaller detailed changes in Constraint Layout) 
and use those both

app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"

The bias is used to move your image or view around the display with a % step, so it takes the device's display and applies your image according to the % bias you have set.

Play with them and you will find a solution

I guess 0.5 Horizontal and 0.1 Vertical will be fine

Your ImageView can look something like this

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/Hi"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dp directly in layouts make things worse with different screen sizes.

you can use the following library to give flexible size to components 
https://github.com/intuit/sdp

and you can use dimensions as follows :

```
android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp
```

And for text sizes use the following library.
https://github.com/intuit/ssp

and use it for text size

```
android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
```

Answer (score 0):

change the code to this and this happen app:layoutconstraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" app:layoutconstraintVertical_bias="0.1"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QEYe.png)